# Sonar 4.1.1 : how to write custom xpath rule for PHP

Tags: sonarqube

I saw some post on SO referring to xPath templates for PHP. But the version I am currently using (4.1.1) does not have those templates anymore.

Does somebody know how to add custom rules from this version on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer possible to add custom rules for PHP. We'll eventually add the support of writing custom rules in Java (as it is currently the case for Java and COBOL). See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules.

Note that if you think that your custom rules might benefit others, you can submit them on the developer list (http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/). If we find them valuable, we'll implement them.